# CSS-transition flickering on hover

Tags: css, css-transitions

awesome that you use your precious time to read my question!

I'm trying to flip a div on hover. All goes fine but it flickers during the transition. It almost looks like it's flipping multiple times! This ruins the whole effect of the flip. Here follows my code and a fiddle:

The fiddle: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/h463d8p6/1/)

And for the *CSS*:

```
.rotate {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    padding:20px;
    background-color: #333;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-top: #E9F01D 3px solid;
}
.rotate:hover {
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    color: #E9F01D;
    cursor: pointer;
    -ms-transform: rotatex(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotatex(360deg);
    transform: rotatex(360deg);
}
```

Is this flicker effect preventable or not? If so how do I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try adding this > -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;

Comment: It seems when you are hovering and shrinking the div, your mouse pointer leaves the div (because it shrinks), causing it to grow again until your mouse pointer touches it again. A possible solution may be to put the :hover on a parent element

Comment: @fboes Wouldn't that result in exactly the same effect on the parent element? I'm going to try it anyway, just wondering..

Comment: I tried it at http://jsfiddle.net/h463d8p6/2/ - is it better for you?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments:

The main trouble is: While hovering over a moving (or animated) div, you may just un-hover from the element because it moves beneath your cursor.

Solution: Place the hover-selector on a containing element which does not alter its size while you hover:

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/h463d8p6/2)**.

```css
.rotate {
  width: 200px; height:80px;
  background:green;
}

.rotate .rotate-inner {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
     -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
      -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
          transition: all 0.3s;
  
  padding:20px;
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  border-top: #E9F01D 3px solid;
}

.rotate:hover .rotate-inner {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  color: #E9F01D;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  -webkit-transform: rotatex(360deg);
     -moz-transform: rotatex(360deg);
      -ms-transform: rotatex(360deg);
          transform: rotatex(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate">
    <div class="rotate-inner">HOVER ME</div>
</div>
```