# Prevent twitching buttons on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a button that on hover will go up by `10px`. The problem is if the cursor is positioned at just barely under the button when the button is transitioned or transitioning by `10px`, it twitches.

```css
.talk-to-us {
    padding: 10px; 
    height: 43px;
    width: 148px;
    background-color: #00cdac;
    position: relative;
    transition: top ease .40s;
    top: 0;
}

.talk-to-us:hover {
    top: -10px;
}

.link {
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px; 
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button class="talk-to-us">
  <a class="link" href="#">TALK TO US!</a>
</button>
```

How do I prevent this behavior solely by CSS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26101314/css-transition-flickering-on-hover

Comment: The reason for it is because you move the button out from under the cursor on hover so that `:hover` is no longer true.

Comment: Ah. So I should wrap it in a container.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS-transition flickering on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26101314/css-transition-flickering-on-hover)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be to add a pseudo element that extends downward far enough to account for the upward shift, so the mouse remains within the target area. With a transparent background you won't see it but it still captures mouse events.

The only change here is the addition of the `::after` selector/rules:

```css
.talk-to-us {
    padding: 10px; 
    height: 43px;
    width: 148px;
    background-color: #00cdac;
    position: relative;
    transition: top ease .40s;
    top: 0;
}

.talk-to-us:hover {
    top: -10px;
}

.talk-to-us:hover::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  background: transparent;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
}


.link {
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px; 
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button class="talk-to-us">
  <a class="link" href="#">TALK TO US!</a>
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd go with the answer in the comments. Put up a container around the button. Seems simpler and something I can wrap my head around.

Comment: Suit yourself. I personally don't like adding DOM elements for this kind of thing, and your question specifically said "How do I prevent this behavior solely by CSS?". Cheers.